# How to calculate balance from credit and debit?

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions, analytic-functions

How to get balance amount based on credit `CRD` and debit `DEB` for each customer `cust` from following `txn_tbl` table

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM txn_tbl;

CUS        AMT TXN_CDE
--- ---------- ----------
A          500 CRD
B          400 CRD
A          350 CRD
C          235 DEB
C          800 CRD
B          132 DEB
D          673 CRD
```

This is the query that i had tried

```
SELECT cust, LAG(amt,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY cust ORDER BY cust) "Bal"
 FROM 
(SELECT cust, SUM(amt)amt
 FROM txn_tbl
 GROUP BY cust, txn_cde
 ORDER BY 2);
```

Comment: You should include any queries that you have tried.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Now i edited my question

Comment: A simple aggregation (`SUM()` function with a `GROUP BY` clause) will do.

Comment: @Nvr please can you show us what do you expect to get from the sample data you shown. What will be the result after the query. Cheers! Also, I see prom your past questions: do you know you can accept the answer that is correct ? Do you know you can vote up for the answer that is helpful to you ?

Comment: @VBoka i dont know about vote.please guide me about upvoting

Comment: @Nvr, VERY NICE. I am sure a lot of people will be happy to see some exstra points from you :) Cheers!

Comment: Is there a pre-existing 'beginning balance' that is not accounted for in your sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the *running* balance, you can do a window sum with conditional logic:

```
select 
    t.*,
    sum(case when txn_cde = 'CRD' then amt else -amt end) 
        over(partition by cus order by id) running_balance
from mytable
```

For this to work, you need a column that can be used to *order* the records; I assumed `id`.

On the other hand, if you want the overall balance per customer (so just one record per customer in the resultset), you can use the same logic with aggregation (and you don't need an ordering colum):

```
select cus, sum(case when txn_cde = 'CRD' then amt else -amt end) balance
from mytable
group by cus
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just sum up your amounts. The trick is to make your credit (or debit, it's not clear) a negative:

```
SELECT cust, Sum(CASE WHEN TXN_CODE = 'DEB' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END * amt) as
FROM txn_tbl 
GROUP BY cust
```